# jOOQ converter implicitly set a value when writing a record

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In a table of my postgresql db, I have 2 columns with default value.

I define a converter for one of them in jOOQ generator configuration.

When i execute the function record.store(), the default value is well used for the field without converter but not for the other one that becomes null.

I never explicitly set those fields but I guess that record.changed(MY_OBJECT.FIELD) == true after the execution of the converter.

I'm not sure this is the expected behavior. Is it a bug ? Is there a workaround for that ?

Edit : Here is the code used

TimestampBinding.java

```
public class TimestampBinding implements Binding<Timestamp, Instant> {

    private static final Converter<Timestamp, Instant> converter = new TimestampConverter();

    private final DefaultBinding<Timestamp, Instant> delegate = new DefaultBinding<> (converter());

    @Override
    public Converter<Timestamp, Instant> converter() { return converter; }

    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.sql(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.register(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.set(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.set(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.get(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.get(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<Instant> ctx) throws SQLException {
        delegate.get(ctx);
    }
}
```

TimestampConverter.java

```
public class TimestampConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, Instant> {
    @Override
    public Instant from(Timestamp ts) {
        return ts == null ? null : ts.toInstant();
    }
    @Override
    public Timestamp to(Instant instant) {
        return instant == null ? null : Timestamp.from(instant);
    }
    @Override
    public Class<Timestamp> fromType() { return Timestamp.class; }
    @Override
    public Class<Instant> toType() { return Instant.class; }
}
```

sql

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  created_at timestamptz DEFAULT now()
);
```

store record

```
user.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
UserRecord userRecord = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_3)
                .newRecord(userTable.USER, user);
userRecord.store();
```

Comment: That's quite possibly a bug. Could you perhaps show some code to help reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just added the code, thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is "expected" and has a long history in jOOQ. The short explanation is here:

- Your column `active` is `NOT NULL`, thus the Java value `null` is interpreted as being the SQL value `DEFAULT`, regardless of the `Record.changed()` flag.
- Your column `created_at` is nullable, thus the Java value `null` is interpreted

  - as being the SQL value `DEFAULT` if `Record.changed(CREATED_AT) == false`
  - as being the SQL value `NULL` if `Record.changed(CREATED_AT) == true`

With your call to `DSLContext.newRecord()`, you are copying all values from your `user` POJO into your `userRecord`, including all the `null` values. jOOQ cannot distinguish between `null` values that are uninitalised and `null` values that are explicitly... `null`.

In your particular case, the best solution would be to declare all columns `NOT NULL` (which is better on a conceptual level anyway):

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

Comment: I agree with you on the conceptual level so I have changed the created_at column to NOT NULL nevertheless I have the following error : null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint. In that case, don't you think jOOQ should remove the column with the null value of the query so that postgresql affects the default value ?

Comment: Not sure I was clear in my previous comment but in my latest test "created_at" is NOT NULL and the java null is not interpreted as DEFAULT. It means that the expected behavior is not respected in my case. Any idea ?

Comment: Defaults should apply on `null` when a column is `NOT NULL`. But only in the latest versions. What version are you using?

Comment: I was using 3.7.3 and I have just switched to 3.8.0. Now it works as explained in your answer, thank you !